# Magnolia CMS 6.2 Custom Field

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

How can I get the item value from JCR for custom field factory in Magnolia version 6.2?
In the earlier version of Magnolia, in Abstract FieldFactory implementations was the property Item item. Since version 6.2. it is no longer there.

```html
public class CustomFieldFactory extends AbstractFieldFactory<String, CustomFieldDefinition> {
    @Inject
    public CustomFieldFactory(CustomFieldDefinition definition, ComponentProvider componentProvider) {
        super(definition, componentProvider);
    }

    public Component createFieldComponent() {
        Object field;
        if (((CustomFieldDefinition)this.getDefinition()).getRows() > 1) {
            TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
            textArea.setRows(((SalesVolumeFromDataHubFieldDefinition)this.getDefinition()).getRows());
            field = textArea;
        } else {
            field = new TextField();
        }
  
        if (((CustomFieldDefinition)this.getDefinition()).getMaxLength() != -1) {
            ((AbstractTextField)field).setMaxLength(((CustomFieldDefinition)this.getDefinition()).getMaxLength());
            MaxLengthIndicatorExtension.extend((AbstractTextField)field);
        }

        ((AbstractTextField)field).setPlaceholder(((CustomFieldDefinition)this.getDefinition()).getPlaceholder());
        return (Component)field;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject `ValueContext<Node>` into the field factory constructor.
Then you can retrieve it via

```
Node dialogNode = valueContext.getSingleOrThrow();
Property thisFieldProperty = dialogNode.getProperty(getDefinition().getName());
```

[Here](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/ui.pub/browse/magnolia-ui-framework-jcr/src/test/java/info/magnolia/ui/field/factory/ValueContextAccesingFieldFactory.java#77) is a test example.

Comment: thanks! but with valueContext all nodes are delivered but I only need the current one. how can I filter out the Node with current property?

Comment: I've extended the answer above. It's worth mentioning that you can use the property value to set some component properties (like readOnly etc.) but the field value shouldn't be initialized in the factory (the value is read from the JCR property named as the field definition itself later with binding mechanism).  So it depends what do you want to do with the property?

Comment: I would like to create a fieldComponent button at click on which an email is sent.
Unfortunately, when I use the code, an exception Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception occurs.
        Node dialogNode = valueContext.getSingleOrThrow();
        try {
            Property thisFieldProperty = dialogNode.getProperty("email");
        } catch (RepositoryException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: You might be hitting https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-6795, which was fixed in version 6.2.17. Which version are you using?

Comment: Be aware that the workaround with `observe()` should be disposed when the email is sent, otherwise it gets triggered every time the `valueContext` is changed.

Comment: Thank you :) I had the version 6.2.16. After updating the version to 6.2.19 everything runs without problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected GenericButton createFieldComponent() {
    Node node = valueContext.getSingleOrThrow();
    GenericButton button = new GenericButton();
    button.setButtonCaption("Senden");
    button.setVisible(true);
    button.getButton().addClickListener(createButtonClickListener(node));

    return button;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).